# creating push notifications in android using javafx

Tags: android, mobile, javafx, gluon, javafxports

Am I new to Android Development using javafx ,and I have created a sample app using **javafx** (using FXports and gluon plugin ).
So Far apps works good in the android phone.
But, I want to use android APIs in my javafx project and create a push Notification that appears on startup of the app.
How Do I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the Gluon's open source [library](https://bitbucket.org/gluon-oss/charm-down) Charm Down. There is a plugin for Push Notifications for both Android and iOS.

If you have already created a project with the Gluon plugin, you can add this plugin:

```
jfxmobile {
    downConfig {
        version = '3.2.4'
        plugins 'display', 'lifecycle', 'push-notifications', 'statusbar', 'storage'
    }
    ...
}
```

As for its use, see the docs [here](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/index.html?com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/LocalNotificationsService.html): you will find what steps are required to use the service.

To enable push notifications on Android, go to [Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com), sign up or sign in, create a new project. To the right of the Overview option, click the settings button, select project settings, and select the Cloud Messaging tab.

[image: Firebase]

Retrieve the Sender ID and add it to your app. The main application `postInit` method is a good place for it:

```
@Override
public void postInit(Scene scene) {
    Services.get(PushNotificationsService.class).ifPresent(service -> {
         service.register(435XXXXXX);
         service.tokenProperty.addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
              System.out.println("Device token: " + nv);
         });
    });
}
```

Before deploying, you need to add the required configuration referred in the docs to the AndroidManifest file.

Finally deploy to your device, and check (with `adb logcat`) that it prints out its device token, you will need it, and the Server Key from Firebase, to be able to send a push notification to that device.

Comment: what for  'PushNotificationsService.class' is used for?

Comment: Add the plugin to the build.gradle file, reload the project so it downloads and includes its jar. Then you will be able to import the `PushNotificationsService` class.

Comment: how about LocalNotificationsServices.class does it works or Not! @jose Perada

Comment: Why not? You can try it as well. Check the documentation for that plugin

Comment: i have tried LocalNotficationServices.class its Not working

Comment: Create a new question for this, posting the relevant code you have tried.

Comment: here's the new Question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42598628/gluon-mobile-localnotificationsservices-class-not-working)